# Not able to check angular version

Tags: angular, npm, compiler-errors, version, command-prompt

I have node version 10.14.1 and npm version 6.4.1. I installed angular version 7.0.3. But when I run ng --version command to check angular version, it is showing error message in command prompt

C:\Users\indhumadhi.k>ng v
ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\Users\indhumadhi.k\node_modules'
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\Users\indhumadhi.k\node_modules'
at Object.readdirSync (fs.js:783:3)
at VersionCommand.run (C:\Users\indhumadhi.k\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\commands\version-impl.js:48:41)
at VersionCommand.validateAndRun (C:\Users\indhumadhi.k\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\models\command.js:123:31)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:744:11)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:285:19)
at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:739:3)

Answer (score -1):

To check the installed Angular version you have to run `ng version` not `ng --version`

Comment: They're running `ng v`, which is shorthand for `ng version` - https://angular.io/cli/version

Answer (score -2):

The ng cli isn't installed globally it seems.